# WhiteSource Scanning distroless docker images: not able to extract layer.tar

Tags: docker

I'm trying to increase security by using distroless image for my containers, using this image from google as base image https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/tree/master/java

When I'm trying to scan it locally with the command
`java -jar wss-unified-agent.jar -apiKey $API_KEY -wss.url $URL -c whitesource-docker.properties -project mytestproject -product mytestproduct`

I receive some warns in the log and 0 system packages. As result, no new projects created

```
[INFO] [2020-02-21 18:09:01,051 +0700] - Extracting file /tmp/WhiteSource-Docker_507e746a-ee9f-4158-b2c5-22d13f4da998/gcr.io-distroless-java.tar - Size 197453824 Bytes (188 MBs)- Free Space 227714412544 Bytes (217165 MBs)
[WARN] [2020-02-21 18:09:01,589 +0700] - Error extracting file layer.tar: /tmp/WhiteSource-Docker_507e746a-ee9f-4158-b2c5-22d13f4da998/gcr.io-distroless-java/7bff0f034dc797b09394b6136265054e798556abd7438fa31417f04302f23db7/./usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/copyright (No such file or directory)
[WARN] [2020-02-21 18:09:01,590 +0700] - Was not able to extract layer.tar (docker image TAR file)
[INFO] [2020-02-21 18:09:03,711 +0700] - Found 0 system packages in image 'gcr.io/distroless/java'
```

In my `whitesource-docker.properties` I have this option
`docker.includes=my_distroless gcr.io/distroless/java`

Is it expected behavior?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Run the commandline as administrator
and verify you have enough space on your machine